# How to prevent visual studio from opening a std header on exception while debuging?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Whenever I debug my program and exception raises Visual studio opens a header of standard library to show me where an error encured. That future drives me realy nuts because I have to close that std file every time on debug, otherwise I can't see my code.

Is there a way to disable that annoying, yellow "pain in the neck" future?

Comment: I searched this once, and IIRC the answer was "you can't, except if you are willing to hardcode every single 'system' header (boost is also annoying) in a obscure registry key". I'm afraid we have to live around this. Use more breakpoints.

Comment: See http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/visual-studio-msvc-debugging-NoStepInto.html I wish there were a "step into the outermost function call of this line" in visual C++...

Comment: Found [this](http://www.litwindow.com/Knowhow/wxHowto/wxhowto.html#nostepinto) on my first [search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=visual+studio+step+into+header).

Comment: Thank you for these useful links, I think using breakpoints is far more simple way..

Comment: Just use the call stack window, dock it to the left hand side, and double-click the function you want to look at.